# Regarding alignment of text in RichTextField

Tags: blackberry, alignment, field, richtext

I have seen many Alignment
But is their anything like Align Justify in Microsoft Word as  in Blackberry for better viewing in Blackberry
i know there is TEXT_ALIGN_HCENTER and others but is there like Align Justify in BB for text display in Blackberry?

Answer (score 1):

use RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_HCENTER in RichTextField property.it work same as you need.

```
RichTextField textData = new RichTextField("sample text",RichTextField.USE_ALL_WIDTH |RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_HCENTER );
```

Comment: i need it like a Align Justify type of Microsoft Word has

Comment: it has default setting of justify alignment You need not to do any thing extra. first You add RichtextField to any FieldManager and specify height and width as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u try this same logic for textfield as well.Hope it works!

```
     add(new LabelField(" Name ",LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER | LabelField.NON_FOCUSABLE));
```

Comment: i need it like a Align Justify type of Microsoft Word has

Comment: i believe theres nothing of dat sort in blackberry.Wonder why u need a justify.Above code works well for most.